# Is there a way I can build a "modular desk" around this case?

Tags: case

I have a mobility and space issue.  I moved from a 5000 sq. ft. house to a 1200 sq ft condominium, and have two computers each sharing the Thermaltake WP200 chassis:

[image: I have the addon box on the bottom featured here.]

While the machine is on castors and I have all hardwood floors, its sheer mass makes it too large to fit under a desk.   This means, with a desk the same depth next to it, I lose enough space in my living room to block the TV from other users when I sit in my chair.  Unfortunately, I don't have a lot of options for locations without blocking the hallway.

What I'd like to do is eliminate the desk entirely by affixing some sort of swing arms for monitors and peripherals that can fold down to the sides or top of the case when not in use.  Monitors can remain upright.   Unfortunately, my own research just keeps turning up wall mounts and nothing that would give me the vertical range of motion needed for the task.

What can I use to turn this beast into a self-contained rolling cart of computing awesomeness so I can eliminate using a full sized desk entirely?  I need to be able to fit 3 monitors, a mouse, a keyboard, a joystick, and a flight throttle as needed.

Comment: Have you tried just putting your desk on blocks so it raises it high enough for your case to slide underneath.  Does that work?  Maybe add a couple screws to secure the blocks to the desk.

Comment: Additionally, define build, are you suggesting you have woodwork or metal working skills and can actually build something?

Comment: I think that this question may technically be out of scope for our site via our definition of [hardware](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265/what-is-hardware).

Answer (score 1):

Place this on top and 3 monitors solved

[https://www.amazon.com/Mount-Freestanding-Compatible-MI-2789-Horizontal/dp/B01HSJX1FG/ref=asc_df_B01HSJX1FG/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=198069575723&hvpos=1o2&hvnetw=g&hvrand=15351618312070035641&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9018840&hvtargid=pla-348819333100&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01HSJX1FG)

[image]
FULLY ADJUSTABLE TRIPLE MONITOR STAND - Triple arms are height adjustable on the vertical pole. Side arms can articulate in three different locations for best positioning of the screens. Each monitor can tilt up 80 or down 45 degrees and rotate 360 degrees. Side monitors can swivel 360 degrees. Rotating the monitor holders allows landscape or portrait positioning. No need to remove the monitors to change positions.

This is just one of many "desk mount 3 monitor" search results

For the rest, I guess it just depends on how elaborate or simple you want to be.  The ultra lazy would just put a cut down sheet of plywood on the top, and the monitor stand.  Resting the keyboard, mouse, and etc on the plywood.

Since you bought a 4x8 sheet plywood you probably have extra, and could probably cut out 2 pieces one for the right and left side and screw them together.  It maybe desirable to add a piece across the back, or front to add addition strength depending on the type of wood selected.

[google](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1&ei=HZlCXNyMNeOUjwSFsaS4Cw&q=desktop%20mount%20for%203%20%20monitor&oq=desktop%20mount%20for%203%20%20monitor&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i299l2.13345.13999..14765...0.0..0.93.233.3......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i8i7i30.BfuKYHU7NlE)

------------Answer #2

[https://www.amazon.com/LUXOR-Standup-CF48-DW-Stand-Crank-Adjustable/dp/B00Y1QDFJM/ref=sr_1_4?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1547869705&sr=1-4&keywords=adjustable+height+desk](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00Y1QDFJM)

Amazon/Google has dozens of adjustable height desks, including sit/stand desks.

[image: sit stand desk]
Overall Dimensions with casters: 48"W x 29.5"D x 32.6" to 48.5"H, Adjustable Height Range: **Between 26"-51.6"H**

[your case](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01C71Q8WS)

Amazon says your case is 27" tall recommend table has that easily handle as it can go as high as 51" and as low as 26".